# Provisioning a wordpress user/blog

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook

I have a wordpress blog inside the company where I write blogs. I want the people inside the organization to comment on the blogs. I was able to grok through the authentication inside the company and get the person's username. I want to auto register a user if he/she doesn't already exist in the system based on their username. Can someone point me to a resource on how to get this done? I know that wordpress has hooks to different functions. Can I just call a function with a person's username and auto register/login the person as a subscriber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to hack wp-cas plugin and provision accounts for people who signed in and came. Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

How do people authenticate within your company? There might be plugins which do what you are looking for. E.q. for LDAP authentication:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-ldap-login/

Comment: Its CAS and I did try the CAS authentication and wpcas plugins. Both don't work out of the box with Wordpress 3. The wpcas plugin worked but the provisioning part didn't. That's the reason I have to do the provisioning manually.